# svg animatetransform working on firefox but not on chrome/ie

Tags: javascript, svg, cross-browser, jquery-animate

I am using a interval method to transform the hands of a clock. The clock is working as expected in Firefox but not in Chrome and IE.

Moreover, there are no errors on console. but the transform attributes seems to be updating timely, but the ui is not getting updated.

```js
var clock = document.querySelector('#clock');
var hands = [];
var cx = 110;
var cy = 110;

function init() {
  hands.push(clock.querySelector('#second > *'));
  hands.push(clock.querySelector('#minute > *'));
  hands.push(clock.querySelector('#hour > *'));

  setInterval(function () {
     transformHands();
   }, 1000);
};

function transformHands() {
  var now = new Date();
  var hours = 360 * now.getHours() / 12 + now.getMinutes() / 2;
  var minutes = 360 * now.getMinutes() / 60;
  var seconds = 360 * now.getSeconds() / 60;
  
  hands[0].setAttribute('from', shifter(seconds));
  hands[0].setAttribute('to', shifter(seconds + 360));
  hands[1].setAttribute('from', shifter(minutes));
  hands[1].setAttribute('to', shifter(minutes + 360));
  hands[2].setAttribute('from', shifter(hours));
  hands[2].setAttribute('to', shifter(hours + 360));
}

function shifter(value){
  return [value, cx, cy].join(' ');
}

init();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

div.container {
  border: 5px solid #333;
  display: block;
  width:220px;
  height:220px;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#border {
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  fill: #eee;
}

#digits > line {
  stroke: #333;
}

#digits > text {
  fill: #333;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-anchor: middle;
  dominant-baseline: central;
}

#hour {
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}

#minute {
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

#second {
  stroke: dodgerblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

#cap {
  stroke: dodgerblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  fill: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <svg id='clock' width='220' height='220'>
        <g id='face'>
            <circle id='border' cx='110' cy='110' r='95'></circle>
        </g>
        <g id='digits'>
            <line x1='110' y1='22' x2='110' y2='33' transform='rotate(30 110 110)'></line>
            <line x1='110' y1='22' x2='110' y2='33' transform='rotate(60 110 110)'></line>
            <text x='192.5' y='110'>III</text>
            <line x1='110' y1='22' x2='110' y2='33' transform='rotate(120 110 110)'></line>
            <line x1='110' y1='22' x2='110' y2='33' transform='rotate(150 110 110)'></line>
            <text x='110' y='192.5'>VI</text>
            <line x1='110' y1='22' x2='110' y2='33' transform='rotate(210 110 110)'></line>
            <line x1='110' y1='22' x2='110' y2='33' transform='rotate(240 110 110)'></line>
            <text x='27.5' y='110'>IX</text>
            <line x1='110' y1='22' x2='110' y2='33' transform='rotate(300 110 110)'></line>
            <line x1='110' y1='22' x2='110' y2='33' transform='rotate(330 110 110)'></line>
            <text x='110' y='27.5'>XII</text>
        </g>
        <g id='hands'>
            <line id='hour' x1='110' y1='110' x2='110' y2='55'>
                <animateTransform attributeName='transform' attributeType='XML' type='rotate'></animateTransform>
            </line>
            <line id='minute' x1='110' y1='110' x2='110' y2='44'>
                <animateTransform attributeName='transform' attributeType='XML' type='rotate'></animateTransform>
            </line>
            <line id='second' x1='110' y1='110' x2='110' y2='33'>
                <animateTransform attributeName='transform' attributeType='XML' type='rotate'></animateTransform>
            </line>
            <circle id='cap' cx='110' cy='110' r='3'></circle>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

I don't know what am I missing. Any help will be appreciated.

Please see the demo here https://codepen.io/rkpaswan_in/pen/aqPPVQ

Answer (score 1):

IE/Edge don't support SMIL animation.  If you want it to work in IE, you'll need to use the [FakeSmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/) polyfill.

As for Chrome, I guess it is not updating the animation if you modify the attributes. You should [report that to Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list).

There is a simple fix though.  Set your `begin` attribute to `"indefinite"`

```
<animateTransform ... begin="indefinite"></animateTransform>
```

Then start the animation running after you set the attributes.

```
hands[0].beginElement();
```

```js
var clock = document.querySelector('#clock');
var hands = [];
var cx = 110;
var cy = 110;

function init() {
  hands.push(clock.querySelector('#second > *'));
  hands.push(clock.querySelector('#minute > *'));
  hands.push(clock.querySelector('#hour > *'));

  setInterval(function () {
     transformHands();
   }, 1000);
};

function transformHands() {
  var now = new Date();
  var hours = 360 * now.getHours() / 12 + now.getMinutes() / 2;
  var minutes = 360 * now.getMinutes() / 60;
  var seconds = 360 * now.getSeconds() / 60;
  
  hands[0].setAttribute('from', shifter(seconds));
  hands[0].setAttribute('to', shifter(seconds + 360));
  hands[0].beginElement();
  hands[1].setAttribute('from', shifter(minutes));
  hands[1].setAttribute('to', shifter(minutes + 360));
  hands[1].beginElement();
  hands[2].setAttribute('from', shifter(hours));
  hands[2].setAttribute('to', shifter(hours + 360));
  hands[2].beginElement();
}

function shifter(value){
  return [value, cx, cy].join(' ');
}

init();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

div.container {
  border: 5px solid #333;
  display: block;
  width:220px;
  height:220px;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#border {
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  fill: #eee;
}

#digits > line {
  stroke: #333;
}

#digits > text {
  fill: #333;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-anchor: middle;
  dominant-baseline: central;
}

#hour {
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}

#minute {
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

#second {
  stroke: dodgerblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

#cap {
  stroke: dodgerblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  fill: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <svg id='clock' width='220' height='220'>
        <g id='face'>
            <circle id='border' cx='110' cy='110' r='95'></circle>
        </g>
        <g id='digits'>
            <line x1='110' y1='22' x2='110' y2='33' transform='rotate(30 110 110)'></line>
            <line x1='110' y1='22' x2='110' y2='33' transform='rotate(60 110 110)'></line>
            <text x='192.5' y='110'>III</text>
            <line x1='110' y1='22' x2='110' y2='33' transform='rotate(120 110 110)'></line>
            <line x1='110' y1='22' x2='110' y2='33' transform='rotate(150 110 110)'></line>
            <text x='110' y='192.5'>VI</text>
            <line x1='110' y1='22' x2='110' y2='33' transform='rotate(210 110 110)'></line>
            <line x1='110' y1='22' x2='110' y2='33' transform='rotate(240 110 110)'></line>
            <text x='27.5' y='110'>IX</text>
            <line x1='110' y1='22' x2='110' y2='33' transform='rotate(300 110 110)'></line>
            <line x1='110' y1='22' x2='110' y2='33' transform='rotate(330 110 110)'></line>
            <text x='110' y='27.5'>XII</text>
        </g>
        <g id='hands'>
            <line id='hour' x1='110' y1='110' x2='110' y2='55'>
                <animateTransform attributeName='transform' attributeType='XML' type='rotate' begin="indefinite"></animateTransform>
            </line>
            <line id='minute' x1='110' y1='110' x2='110' y2='44'>
                <animateTransform attributeName='transform' attributeType='XML' type='rotate' begin="indefinite"></animateTransform>
            </line>
            <line id='second' x1='110' y1='110' x2='110' y2='33'>
                <animateTransform attributeName='transform' attributeType='XML' type='rotate' begin="indefinite"></animateTransform>
            </line>
            <circle id='cap' cx='110' cy='110' r='3'></circle>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: By the way, if you are setting the hand positions every second, you don't need to be using `<animateTransform>`.